# How to keep earphones properly in ears while riding

Tags: travel, headphones

Some of the ear phones doesnot fit in ears . While riding bike for direction purpose we need earphones (if we donot have bluetooth headset) . It always falls and distracts while riding . Is there any idea to overcome this?

Comment: Thank you for safety suggestion , I know it is dangerous to ride wearing ear phones . But my purpose is for google map navigation in  a city . Where i need to wear earphones . If you have any idea on this i am ready to accept .

Comment: Some sort of GPS device clipped onto your bike with a visual display?

Comment: @user3791372 that sounds even worse than listening to directions in your ear.  I would think taking my eyes off the road would be a much worse distraction than hearing a voice in my ear.  there are headphones that allow outside sound to pass through nearly uninterrupted

Comment: Some companies offer aftermarket tips in different shapes or materials for some in-ear headphones to improve comfort and sound, but they can also improve the support a bit. The downside is that they usually achieve this through improving isolation, so you should get earphones that *don't* isolate you from the outside in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than buying sports earphones, the simplest solution is to hook the earphones over your ear. Although not entirely foolproof, this prevents the earphone being slowly pulled out of your ear, or at least reduces how often it happens. Your ear absorbs some of the tugging, and the positioning within the ear canal is generally more resistant to the earbud being pulled out.

[image: Earphone with cord passing over earlobe]

Comment: There are  also in-ear headphones that have a rigid plastic part that hook over your ear. I've found them more comfortable that doing this, but both will work.

Comment: 'Other than buying sports earphones' - I covered that in the first sentence :) this answer was about the life hack way to make your own (not quite as good) version

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Skim-reading fail.

Comment: Other than what Jon Story has said, in addition I used to tie a kerchief after inserting the earphones. This ensures proper and tight fit. You can also try to create a custom moulded earphone with this [DIY](http://www.instructables.com/id/Easy-Custom-Fit-Earphones/) hack.